# Does transconductance of a NMOS in saturation vary if I double both 'W' and 'L'?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, transconductance, current-drain

Gm for a mosfet in saturation is 2Id/Vov. Vov is constant and we expected the Id to be a constant too for both cases since Id(sat)=0.5*UnCox (W/L)(Vov^2), W/L is unchanged and there for Id should be a constant and therefore we expected gm to be a constant.

But when we tried to simulate it in LTSPICE,[image] Id for different W and L were different.(W/L ratio remained same, varied W and L in same proportion).

Can someone explain the reason for it?
[image]

[image: Technology file]

Comment: That's not what I get with a [quick hack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6otLc.png). What settings did you use? What `.model`? How was the test schematic prepared?

Comment: I used a TSMC180nm technology file. The LTSPICE circuit is attached with the question. @aconcernedcitizen

Comment: Are you sure that 1 V is enough to drive it into saturation? Have you tried a `.DC` to check the curves for this `.model`?

Comment: yes Vtho is close to 0.36Volt, and we gave Vgs=Vds therefore its always in saturation. @aconcernedcitizen

Comment: You're using tsmc180nm, which is a submicron process. You should be aware of both short-channel effects and the fact that the model you posted may *potentially* be under an NDA (my access to TSMC's models happens to be under one)

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the **drawn** W and L...the dimensions that the chip designer specifies for the masks. After the transistor is manufactured the **effective** W and L will be slightly different because the implants for the source and drain will diffuse a bit under the gate.

I don't remember exactly which parameters of the Level 3 model control this behavior, but it is pretty well documented online.

Comment: There are also parasitic drain and source resistances. In saturation, the drain R isn't critical, but the source R does affect the system.  Try sweep just W and plot the current vs. W. It will be a straight line with an x-intercept indicating the deltaW that the model uses. Do similar for L